# Create a seamless, tileable image for an angled logo

Tags: css, image, photoshop

This isn't directly a programming question but it does use a bit of maths and css and it's been bugging me for a while now.

My aim is to create an angled logo image (with a logo rotated, say, 35 deg) and make it so it can be tiled. I have referred to [this well thought out question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633444/creating-seamless-rotated-background-image) but I am currently a bit stuck at stage 1.

So say this is my logo:

[image]

It's not so regular in that it has a little icon on the top-left and it isn't set inside a set size rectangle so its boundaries are not obvious.

The first step, I guess, is to make it tileable in its current form. Just applying a css tile rule to it as it stands would result in something like this, which is no good:

[image]

Ideally, before we rotate it we want alternate rows to be offset so it's less *grid-like*.

[image]

The offset should obviously be 50% of the space between the same point on 2 adjoining logos. What is the best way to achieve this step? Do I just copy/paste and drag it until it looks right? This won't be that accurate. (Using photoshop).

I'll then need to determine the crop area so it seamlessly repeats.

Once this is done I have a grid of images that I can now rotate as one in photoshop to my desired angle. The difficulty will be getting the crop area correct. I will then refer to my link above.

The added difficulty is ensuring we have a good sized crop area for the horizontal logos. If the ratio of the edges means we have a very high [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) then my rotated crop area will be huge and pointless.

In summary, what is the best method to reliably set the horizontal grid so we get a crop area with sensible dimensions (e.g. 150 x 100 px)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some strenuous attempts I have cracked it, but only for a 45deg rotation. I'd be interested if anyone could offer advice on how to calculate the crop area for other angles.

- So the first step is to make a horizontal grid of logos like the last example in the question.
  Do this by placing the logo in the top-left of the canvas and then cropping the canvas so the logo just fits inside.
- Next, if necessary resize the canvas to approx the size of the image we want. Aspect ratio is not important at this stage, we just want to have a manageable image size to work work. Something like 250px wide is good. The result of this is likely that you'll have a wierd dimension for the other edge. E.g. 250px wide x 78px high.
- Now we pad the logo with empty space. This will have 2 purposes. First to give a good amount of space between the logos, and second to get a good aspect ratio. This is really important. Try to make your canvas so that one edge is 1/2 or 1/3 of the length of the other edge if possible. This will help us have as low a least common multiple as we can. When resizing the canvas ensure you keep the actual logo in the top-left of the canvas with the padding being from the right and the bottom of the image.
- We'll now want to manually tile the image, but also include the padded area. If we just copy this as it stands photoshop will ignore the padding area and only copy the logo itself. Make a new layer and put it in a layer folder with the logo layer. Fill this layer with a color.
- Now make a new photoshop doc. Make the canvas size pretty large; like 1000px x 1000px.
- Copy the layer folder you just made to this new doc by going layer->duplicate while it's selected and select the new doc as the destination.
- Now tile this folder by duplicating the layer and dragging it. Start by dragging the first copy down and then right. Photoshop helps with this by snapping the layer at key points to the original. You'll find that you can get the duplicated layer to snap when its top edge touches the bottom edge of the original layer, and half-way along the length so it's offset horizontally.
- Keep duplicating and snapping in place until you've mostly covered the large canvas with the tiles.
- Now to make a crop that will produce a tileable image. Get the select tool and choose the `fixed size` option. Enter in a pixel size that makes the selection a square with edges the same length as the longer of your original image. I.e. If your original image was 150px x 50px then you should make your crop size 150px x 150px.
- Click anywhere on your canvas to make the selection, copy-merged to a new doc, and you should find you'll have tileable image you can use, albeit with horizontal logo.
- Now to rotate it. Go to the large tiled doc. Ctrl-D to deselect. Edit-> Rotate the canvas 45deg.
- Now calculate the size of your crop. This is as follows:

  1. Find the least common multiple. So if your dimensions are 150x50 `LCM = 150`.
  2. The size of your crop box is the hypotuse of a right-angled triangle with the other edge lengths = to the LCM. I.e if `LCM = 150`, L = sqrt(150<sup>2</sup> * 150<sup>2</sup>) = 212.12.
- Now make a square crop of size 212 (in this case) of the rotated canvas (anywhere will do). This should be a tileable image you can save, resize, edit etc.

This method worked a treat on my [company's Twitter page](https://twitter.com/IPSCapital)

As I said, any method to calculate the crop size for other angles would be helpful.